# redirection via ht access file is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here is the scenario:

There is a website named *"example.com"* and a folder named *"mobile"* for accessing website via mobile or tab

If a user types just *"example.com"* in browser they should be redirected to https://www.example.com which is working as per the below code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, if a user is accessing the url https://www.example.com from mobile then it should be redirected to https://mobile.example.com

Now, whenever I am accessing the url https://www.example.com from mobile
it redirects the browser to https://mobile.example.com but again as per the code in .htaccess it considers this specific part of url *"example.com"* and redirects browser back to https://www.example.com and this way it finally ends up in infinite loop generating error:

**"Fetching the page exceeded the maximum of 10 redirects."**

I tried putting something like this in .htaccess file so as to not redirect to https://www.example.com in case there is a *"mobile"* word as prefix but it is not working

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^mobile/ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Please advise.

This is how the .htaccess file constructed

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mobile - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{www.example.com}/$1 [R,L]

##DISABLE VIEWING DIRECTORIES##
Options -Indexes
##DISABLE VIEWING DIRECTORIES##

##DISABLE VIEWING DIRECTORIES FILES##
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(png|gif)$ - [F,NC]
##DISABLE VIEWING DIRECTORIES FILES##

##DISABLE VIEWING admin DIRECTORY FILES##
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/.+\.php$ - [F,L]
##DISABLE VIEWING admin DIRECTORY FILES##
```

Redirection code from header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://mobile.example.com";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the RewriteCond correctly. If you want to skip url rewriting when uri is **/mobile/** and redirect **example.com** to **https://www.example.com** you can use the following

```
#Skip url rewriting if requested uri is /mobile
RewriteRule ^mobile - [L]
#redirect example.com/ to http://www.example.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R]
```

**/**  is not a special char in mod-rewrite , you dont need to escape it.

Comment: RewriteRule ^mobile - [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com" R=301,L]                                                                                                   but it is not working the redirection still exist, what is wrong i am doing

Comment: @team Clear your browser cache

Comment: all done... but it is still having the same issue.. I have edited my question and added the full .htaccess file as I am not sure, where is the mistake I am doing

Comment: Any further suggestions ??

Comment: Your edited htaccess works as expected on my server. Can you please explain your issue clearly?

Comment: well, with the same htaccess when I try accessing https://www.example.com in my mobile then it redirects to https://mobile.example.com and then it throws error as follows:   "The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.  "   -->Code from my header.php is added in the question